# IsUpdateable is returning false salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am using force.com sites with VF page and apex controller. In class I am doing update dml operation based on Field Level Security check on fields using  [objectName].fields.getMap().get([fieldApiName]).getDescribe().isUpdateable(). This statement is returning false always even though guest user profile has Edit access on fields.

Removing this if check is a option for now although I am wondering if there is any existing limitation to use this check. Any insights are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce removed the update permission from Guest users a while ago.
[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5)

> - Guest users can’t have more than read access to data
> - Guest users **can’t have the update or delete permissions** on objects. Guest users can only update or delete records in System Mode.

If Guest user profile has create permission on object and edit permission on field, `isCreateable()` will return `true`, but since the profile lacks the update permission `isUpdateable()` will return `false`